# Can't exit the do while loop ，even the expression is false

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.*;
public class number_guassing_game{
    private static int a = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
       int number=(int)(Math.random()*100+1);
       int count=0;
       boolean flag = true;
       do {
           int a = in.nextInt();
           count+=1;
           if(a>number) {
               System.out.println("smaller!");
           }else if(a<number) {
               System.out.println("bigger!");
           }
        }while(a != number); 
        System.out.println("congratulations!"+" You have guessed "+count+" times!");
    }
}
```

[image]

Obviously the answer is 48, but it didn't the loop and print the expression.

Comment: I know that it is important to write readable code, and this program is just a small exercise for my friend to learn basic grammar.Thank you for your reminding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The loops condition

```
while(a != number);
```

doesn't see the local variable into which you read the input:

```
int a = in.nextInt();
```

It sees the static variable initialized to `0` that never changes:

```
private static int a = 0;
```

Therefore the loop never terminates.

You should change

```
int a = in.nextInt();
```

to

```
a = in.nextInt();
```

Oh, and there's no reason for `a` to be `static`. It could be a local variable of the `main` method, as long as it is declared outside (and before) the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The `a` you define inside the loop shadows the `a` from outside it. That `a` is never updated, and thus the loop will only be terminated if you enter `0` (the original value `a` was initialized with). In order to avoid this, just use the same `a` instead of declaring a new variable:

```
a = in.nextInt(); // no datatype here, since you aren't defining a new variable
```